# Check if the chosen day is in a week from today (Joda time)

Tags: android, date, time, jodatime

The App should show the text "the next" in the text view, only if the chosen date is in a week from today, but it doesn't...

I tried this line:

```
(todayDate.withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusWeeks(1).isEqual(eventToDisplay.getEventDate().withTimeAtStartOfDay()))
```

**The other parts of the code are working, only this doesn't**

DateTime todayDate = new DateTime().now();

```
        //If the event's date equal to today's date
        if ((Days.daysBetween(eventToDisplay.getEventDate().withTimeAtStartOfDay(),todayDate.withTimeAtStartOfDay()).getDays())==0)
        {
            contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDayOfTheWeekTxt,"היום"+"("+eventToDisplay.getEventDate().dayOfWeek().getAsText()+")");

        }

        else {

            if (Days.daysBetween(todayDate.withTimeAtStartOfDay(),eventToDisplay.getEventDate().withTimeAtStartOfDay()).getDays()==1)
                contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDayOfTheWeekTxt,"tomorrow"+"("+eventToDisplay.getEventDate().dayOfWeek().getAsText()+")");

            else {

                if ((Days.daysBetween(todayDate.withTimeAtStartOfDay(),eventToDisplay.getEventDate().withTimeAtStartOfDay()).getDays())<7)
                {
                    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDayOfTheWeekTxt, eventToDisplay.getEventDate().dayOfWeek().getAsText()+"The upcoming ");

                }

                else {
                    if (todayDate.withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusWeeks(1).isEqual(eventToDisplay.getEventDate().withTimeAtStartOfDay()))
                    {
                        contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDayOfTheWeekTxt, eventToDisplay.getEventDate().dayOfWeek().getAsText()+"The next");

                    }

                    else
                    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.eventDayOfTheWeekTxt, eventToDisplay.getEventDate().dayOfWeek().getAsText());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: show more code. Log the tostring of these dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
todayDate.withTimeAtStartOfDay().plusWeeks(1)
    .isEqual(eventToDisplay.getEventDate().withTimeAtStartOfDay())
```